# What do brackets mean in C# xml documentation generated by ghost doc?

Tags: c#, xml-comments, ghostdoc

I generated xml-comments to a method with Ghost doc

```
    /// <summary>
    /// Determines whether [is lv class identifier] [the specified class identifier].
    /// </summary>
    /// <param name="classId">The class identifier.</param>
    /// <returns><c>true</c> if [is lv class identifier] [the specified class identifier]; otherwise, <c>false</c>.</returns>
    private static bool IsLVClassId(int classId)
```

and couldn't find any meaning or documentation to this. I would have prefered to generate text like

```
/// Determines whether classid is lv class identifier
```

Anyway can I make it more understandable somehow besides editing the comment  myself (instead of editing some template or provide value for placeholders)?

Comment: This is just a guess, but it looks like placeholders from where it had to infer member names, but it wasn't totally sure about the result.

Comment: it sure looks like some kind of place holders